# Creating a 2D array from a txt file

Tags: java, array

I was told to create a 2D array from a txt file that had the "carModel, carColor" followed by a new line. The 2D array is 8x8 and for each time a certain carmore and carcolor appear, their respective [x][y] coordinate that represents their count goes up by 1.

So far, I have read the file, created a 2D array from the file, and have created an output with the 2D array and every slot filled with zero, but the only way I can seem to figure out to update each model,color count is if I manually make 64 if-statements to check if they appear in the list n+ times. Surely there has to be another way?

For example, When my scanner reads through the list, I need it to check if the list repeats the carmodel, carcolor and if so, update the count of that carmake and color.

This is the code I have thus far:

```
public static void main (String [] args) throws Exception
{
    String [][] cars = new String [8][8]; 
    ArrayList <String> colors = new ArrayList<>();
    colors.add("BLUE  ");
    colors.add("BLACK ");
    colors.add("BROWN ");
    colors.add("GREEN ");
    colors.add("RED   ");
    colors.add("SILVER");
    colors.add("WHITE ");
    Collections.sort(colors);
    ArrayList <String> models = new ArrayList<>();
    models.add("Escape  ");
    models.add("Explorer");
    models.add("F150    ");
    models.add("F250    ");
    models.add("Flex    ");
    models.add("Mustang ");
    models.add("Taurus  ");
    Collections.sort(models);
    cars [0][0] = "_____  ";
    for (int a = 1; a < cars.length; a++)
    {
        cars[0][a] = (models.get(a-1)) + " ";
    }
    for (int b = 1; b < cars.length; b++)
    {
        cars[b][0] = (colors.get(b-1)) + " ";
    }
    for (int fir = 1; fir < cars.length; fir++)
    {
        for (int sec = 1; sec < cars[1].length; sec++)
        {
            if (cars[fir][sec] == null)
            {
                cars[fir][sec] = "0        ";
            }
        }
    }       
    for (int first = 0; first < cars.length; first++)
    {
        for (int second = 0; second < cars[first].length; second++)
        {
            System.out.print(cars[first][second]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }        
    File file = new File ("C:\\Users\\delta\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\SchoolWork\\cars.txt");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
    String ab = sc.nextLine();
        while (ab != null)
        {
            String [] nums = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
            for (int i = 0; i < nums.length;i++)
            {                  
               System.out.println(nums[i]);                    
            }               
        }        
}
```

The output is supposed to look something like this:

[image]

Comment: What is a "carmore?"  Do you mean car model?  And "carcolor" should be two words.

Comment: I'm confused where the "64 if statements" come into play here.  Also I *think* your instructor may have intended you to use a `Map` rather than `ArrayList`, but you had better ask them about that.

Comment: @markspace unfortunately we have not gone over maps at all, the 64 if statements would be manually checking each options, example: create a Set of every carmodel,carcolor and say for each index if that set.contains(carmodel,carcolor) then int carmodelcarcolo +=1, which would require me to manually do that for EVERY single option

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview. Unfortunately, your question is about a part of your code that is not yet written: [off topic with Code Review@SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: (Ah, and please prefer block-quoting text over inserting a pixel raster in your posting - for one thing, pixel rasters will not be found by text searches for years to come.)

Answer (score 1):

- [Consider using `Arrays.asList("", ...)` to create lists in-line.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...))
- Why are `colors` and `models` Lists while `cars` is an Array? It seems like you can use Arrays for all of this.
- [Consider using "anonymous arrays" (terrible name) to create Arrays in-line.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/anonymous-array-java/)
- Consider first building the "true" data structure as `int[][] car_counts = new int[7][7]`, a zero-indexed 2D array of counts. Then treat the task of printing it as shown in the image as a separate problem.
- Your while loop at the end appears to be incorrectly indented.
- That while loop should be building a data-structure that you can neatly read the file into: a list of pairs of strings. (or even a list of pairs of ints, representing indexes into `models` and `colors`.)